# What is the meaning of be?

Tags: verbs

What do we mean by be when we say for e.g. be brave, be mindful.

Does it mean that you are not brave or mindful but become?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is trivial for native speakers and such questions are usually off-topic on this site; please consider the [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) (ELL) Stack Exchange instead.  In addition, the present site has a significant 'research requirement': you are supposed to have attempted to answer the question yourself using commonly available resources and are supposed to summarize this research in the text of your question, explaining why you still don't think you know the answer. The ELL SE also has a research requirement, but it is arguably less strict.

Comment: @linguisticturn I think the question is definitely *not* trivial for native speakers. However, I believe it should be asked at https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/ rather than here. (Either that, or it needs to be clarified to put it clearly in the realm of English rather than metaphysics.)

Comment: @JasonBassford Well, yes; almost anything has a philosophical component if thought about from the right angle. However, since the question *was* asked *here,* I take it as fair to assume it is really about English, e.g. about what a typical native speaker will understand *be brave* to mean [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=RhxFBgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT345&dq=%22be%20brave%22&pg=PT345#v=onepage&q=%22be%20brave%22&f=false). Otherwise, indeed, one should read stuff like [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=zWolBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA102&dq=%22be%20brave%22&pg=PA102#v=onepage&q=%22be%20brave%22&f=false).

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say that "be" means the same as "become" (at least it's not always so).

For example, when we ask someone to **be** patient, we often mean they should **display the quality (of patience)**. But when we say they should **become**/**get** patient, we usually mean they need to **develop the quality** and then show it.

It may not always be so. For example, [this article](https://www.wikihow.com/Be-Patient) teaches readers how to be patient. If we start thinking deeply about what it actually means, it may get tricky. On the one hand, patience is in us, we just need to learn how to exercise it. On the other hand, the article teaches people to *become* patient. So, sometimes there is a fine line between the two concepts.

Comment: Whether *be X*, in such formulations means *display the quality of X* or *develop/acquire/maintain the quality of X*, often depends on the timeframe provided by the context. When a person who is about to face some danger today is told to be brave today, it is clear the person is urged to exercise the virtue of courage, that the person is presumed to already possess. On the other hand, when a young person is told to be brave, in the context of a general conversation about the rest of the person's life, this is likely an exhortation to develop the virtue.